# hide domain name Teams participants keep only their names

Tags: office-365, office, microsoft-teams, external-users, office-365-groups

In order to guarantee the anonymization , participants are asked to hide the name of their company to which they belong in the "Teams

URGENT !!!

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible to do with Teams.

Comment: Can you give me please a microsoft documentation to be able to prove that please

Comment: You should open a support case via admin.microsoft.com if you want an official answer, but recall a username is the basic identifier for all Azure/M365 services.

Comment: Thank you it's clair (y)